# Architecture problem with using another class method in cucumber project

Tags: selenium, cucumber

I recently joined to automated test Java project which uses Cucumber and Selenium.
It is used to test web application. Project structure is divided into 3 layers:

- feature files - which contains cucumber tests scenarios and steps
- glue files - which are binding cucumber step and invoke Java methods
- page files - which contains fields that refers to web page elements and methods to access these elements.

Every glue file has method with `@Before` tag  and  `@additional` tag to make this method be executed before each test scenario in corresponding feature file. Appropriate feature file uses also `@additional` tag to know which `@Before` method should it invoke. Inside each method with `@Before` tag there is a bunch of lines, which initializes some Page files objects, e.g :

Cucumber file:

```
@DesignPage
Scenario: some example scenario
Given HI im cucumber step method
```

Glue file:

```
@Before @DesignPage
public someBeforeMethod(){
...
designPage = new DesignPage();
managmentPage = new ManagmentPage();
...
```

lateron, glue files has methods definition for cucumber steps, which invokes some methods from page files, e.g.:

```
@Given("HI im cucumber step method")
public void HiImCucumberMethod(){
designPage.executeSomeDesignPageMethod();
}
```

Till now everything works fine.

Now lets say that I have another (@MainPage) feature file, but I want to execute exact same method from (DesignPage) feature:

```
@MainPage
Scenario: some example scenario2
Given HI im cucumber step method
```

Cucumber sees from here, that `HI im cucumber step method` is already declared in `DesignPage` glue file, so I want to reuse this method. Unfortunately I will recive NullPointerException - and the reason is clear. `designPage` object which is used in this method was never initialized, because I never executed `@Before` method from `DesignPage` glue file. And the reason is because with this scenario I executed only `@Before` method from different glue file - `MainPage` glue file.

This architecture annoys me a little, because the only solution is to copy-paste `HI im cucumber step method` method from DesignPage glue file to MainPage glue file, initialize design page object in `MainPage` `@Before` class, and then in addition I have to rename `HI im cucumber step method`, because Cucumber sees now two methods with same reference and it don't know which one should use.

I spend on that some time and I have no idea how to change architecture, to be able in one feature reuse method from another feature. Any suggestions will be welcomed.

Comment: How did you do this : I executed only @Before method from different glue file - MainPage glue file.

Comment: Can you share the MainPage glue File code?

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it: the current step definition of `Given HI im cucumber step method` only initializes page objects' instances and it's required to execute the step before each test scenario. If it's true then maybe you should consider moving it to `Before` hook. According to the documentation it's actually designed to do some technical setup before your scenarios.

> Whatever happens in a Before hook is invisible to people who only read the features. You should consider using a background as a more explicit alternative, especially if the setup should be readable by non-technical people. Only use a Before hook for low-level logic such as starting a browser or deleting data from a database.

Learn more: https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/#hooks

Comment: If I understand you correcty, you suggests to intialize page objects in @Before method. If you look at my example before metod,  you will see that objects are actually initialized there. Step method uses only already initialized objects, and thats why I have this nullpointerexception problem.

Comment: Nope, I suggest initializing page objects in a hook, not a step as you do. Please have a look at the documentation I linked, If it isn't still clear I'll elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing objects inside method definition and not inside the before method. Something like this

```
Class GlueFile
{
    DesignPage designPage;
    ManagmentPage managmentPage;

 @Before @DesignPage
 public someBeforeMethod(){
 ...
 }
 @Given("HI im cucumber step method")
 public void HiImCucumberMethod(){
 designPage = new DesignPage();
 managmentPage = new ManagmentPage();
 designPage.executeSomeDesignPageMethod();
 } 

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. Nullpointerexception is still producent.

Comment: So you have two Page object files DesignPage and MainPage and one glue file with step definition and two different feature files design and Main? ?

Comment: Can you try initializing object inside the step definition as I have edited in answer or try making it static.